# Drawing a graph with large values but small change in the values

Tags: algorithm, graphics, graph, plot

I am trying to draw a graph depicting the memory consumption of a process vs the time. I am able to get the memory consumed and draw graph using Qt after taking help from SO. To showcase even minor changes in memory, I am scaling the Y-axis in bytes.

My problem is, usually the memory consumed is a very large value to be showcased in my graph and it shoots out of the visible area.

I studies [here](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch14s09.html) how I can use Logarithmic scale to avoid this problem. But this causes another problem :

After some time, normally the process settles down with the memory initialization and any further change in the memory consumption are very small values compared with the total memory consumed by this process. Thus these changes are not really visible on my graph because of the log I am taking for scaling. But my main aim is to showcase this change in total memory consumption in a graphical format.

Is my approach wrong or there are better ways to achieve this ?

Implementation in Qt/C++/qml, but generic ideas are most welcome.

eg.

Time: 0 Sec | 
Consumption : 0 Bytes

Time: 1 Sec | 
Consumption : 1212120 Bytes

Time: 2 Sec | 
Consumption : 1212520 Bytes

Time: 3 Sec | 
Consumption : 1212720 Bytes

.. consumption settles down around this time -- Now only small changes --

Time: 20 Sec | 
Consumption : 1212890 Bytes

Time: 21 Sec | 
Consumption : 1212893 Bytes

Time: 22 Sec | 
Consumption : 1212895 Bytes

Comment: How about plotting the _delta_ of memory usage? That is, +500 bytes at the 2nd sec, +200 bytes at the 3rd sec, ...

Comment: Get the best of both worlds - show the magnitude on one plot with logarithmic scaling, and on a separate plot show the actual byte count. For the second plot scale the ymin, ymax to 20% of the running average over the last 10 seconds.

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks! Can you please post that as an answer so that I can ask some other queries regarding your solution and perhaps accept it as the answer.

Comment: @timrau But for the first delta interval there will be a sharp peak when the consumption increases from 0 to a very high value and then this change will suddenly drop down to small values. This initial peak will most probably shoot out of my graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A fractional power (such as square root) may be a consideration instead of a logarithm.
- Ignore the first value. If the value at time 0 is always 0, you could consider ignoring it. It significantly offsets your dataset. Then the y-min on the graph can be 1212120 and it would look better:

  [image: Graph]
- Displaying the changes (value at time x - value at time x-1) rather than the actual values (value at time x) may also be a good idea.

Comment: I wanted to know how this idea came to you. Is it that you decided to use the fractional powers because the rate of change for them would be smaller than the rate of change for log function ?

Comment: I've done quite a bit of work with algorithm complexity, which makes one quite familiar with the relation between `n`, `sqrt(n)` and `log(n)`. Essentially I saw you as wanting something between `n` and `log(n)`, which is where `sqrt(n)` fits in.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to approach it:

1. Chart the changes, not the absolute values.
2. Use an inset or small chart, like in a map, that shows the large change in the corner of a chart. In the main part of the chart, show the small changes.
3. Display the value of the memory usage at the current cursor position (a single number) in another corner of the main chart.